# Dynamically generate id for input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have create text boxes using json data.

Now, I want to generate ids for these dynamically generated text boxes so that I can get the value for the text boxes.

I need the code that can generate ids for text box created using json objects.

Comment: Do you have any more info?  Does it matter what the ids are?  If not, just set a counter and iterate over the JSON objects, incrementing the counter as you go.

Answer (score 0):

While you're looping through the objects you want to create, use the index to create an id (or better yet, append the index like `id: 'foo-' + index`.

Here is an example.  The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKS55/) might give you some inspiration.

```
$(function () {
  var json = '[{"foo":"bar","quux":1},{"foo":"bar","quux":2},{"foo":"bar","quux":3}, {"foo":"bar","quux":4}]',
    container = $('#container');

  $.each(JSON.parse(json), function (index, obj) {
    container.append($('<input/>', {
      id: index,
      value: 'my id is' + index
    }));
  });
```

});

Please clarify if this does not answer your question.